# DokuWiki on nginx with public_html directory and URL rewriting

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, dokuwiki

I'm running a DokuWiki installation on an nginx server. The DokuWiki installation is located in `/var/www/` and URL rewriting is activated for this path:

```
    location / {
        root        /var/www;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki;
    }

    location @dokuwiki {
        rewrite ^/_media/(.*) /lib/exe/fetch.php?media=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/_detail/(.*) /lib/exe/detail.php?media=$1 last;
        rewrite ^/_export/([^/]+)/(.*) /doku.php?do=export_$1&id=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/(.*) /doku.php?id=$1 last;
    }
```

Now I want to run a second DokuWiki installation in `/home/$user/public_html/`. I'm using the following rewrite rule for the public_html directory:

```
location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    alias       /home/$1/public_html$2;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ @dokuwiki;
}
```

The installation of DokuWiki to the public_html directory was successful, but some URLs are rewritten to `/var/www/` instead of `/home/$user/public_html/`. Does anyone know how to modify the configuration to allow both DokuWiki installations with URL rewriting side by side?